# VS Code c# intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have installed VS Code on my computer with Linux (ubuntu 16) and I have installed C# extension, but intellisense does't work.

When I tried to find out solution in other sides, I found that I must open a `.sln` file. But I compile all scripts using command line and `.sln` file in most cases doesn't make sense for me. Is there any other way how to enable C# intellisense in VS Code when I open only `*.cs` files?

Answer (score 0):

intellisense I've seen have issues if you have not complied code successfully yet. It tends to be flaky, and usually close/reopen and sometimes full restart is required to get it to pop up again